# Totaling steps following collatz sequence?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm not sure how to get the total number of steps within the collatz sequence, using this code:

```
number = int(input('Enter a number, please:'))  

while number > 1:  
    if number % 2 == 0:  
        number = number / 2  
        print(number)  
    else:  
        number = number * 3 + 1  
        print(number)  
    # print('Steps required:',NEED TO FILL , end='')
```

Comment: Where is the `while` loop you mentioned?

Comment: Hint: You **don't** want to do `number = format(number / 2,'.0f')`. BTW, this pattern is known as the Collatz sequence.

Comment: You can't get _everything_ on one line because the user has to hit `Enter` to input their number. So in your example there will be a newline between the 10 and the 5, but all the other stuff can be on one line. You just need to do `print(number, end=' ')`

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the name of the sequence and I didn't notice but my example wasn't copied correctly. @PM2Ring You are correct, following the user hitting enter each value ( 5, 16,8,4,2,1) are suppose to appear on new lines respectively.

Comment: So I fixed the code a bit but I'm still unsure how to get the total number of steps, using this code:

 `number = int(input('Enter a number, please:'))  

 while number > 1:  
    if number % 2 == 0:  
    number = number / 2   
    print(number)   
 else:  
    number = number * 3 + 1  
     print(number)   

# print('Steps required:',NEED TO FILL , end='')' Can you guys let me know what lines of code to add?  `

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to simply count the steps taken within the `while` loop. Adding a `count` variable and printing the results would look like:

```
number = int(input('Enter a number, please:'))

#initiate step count
steps = 0
while number > 1:
    if number % 2 == 0:
        number = number / 2
        print(number)
    else:
        number = number * 3 + 1
        print(number)
    # add a step for each loop
    steps += 1
print('Steps required: {}'.format(steps))
```

Running this in the shell yields:

```
$ python3 -i collatz.py 
Enter a number, please:14
7.0
22.0
11.0
34.0
17.0
52.0
26.0
13.0
40.0
20.0
10.0
5.0
16.0
8.0
4.0
2.0
1.0
Steps required: 17
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
def collatz(number):

    if(number%2==0):
        n=number//2
        print(n,"\t",end="")
        return n
    else:
        ev=3*number+1
        print(ev,"\t",end="")
        return ev

num1=input("Enter a number: \n")
step=0
try:
    num=int(num1)

    if(num==1):
        print("Enter an integer greater than 1")
    elif(num>1):
        a=collatz(num) 
        while(True):
            if(a==1):
                step=step+1
                break
            else:
                a=collatz(a)
                step+=1
        print("\nNumber of steps needed:",step)

    else:
        print("Please, Enter a positive integer to begin the Collatz sequence")


except:
    print("please, Enter an integer")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#Here's the one I did for the Python institute Collatz task:

c0 = int(input("Input in a number except higher than 1:"))
steps = 0

if c0 <=1:
    c0 = int(input("Input in a number except higher than 1:"))
    
while c0 != 1:
    if c0 %2 == 0:
        c0 = c0//2
        steps +=1
        print(c0)
    if c0 %2 != 0:
        if c0 != 1:
            c0 = 3 * c0 + 1
            print(c0)
            steps +=1
        if c0 == 1:
            print("number of steps:", steps)
```

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.